# Are all the generated Doctrine classes required to be in the Doctrine app directory

Tags: php, doctrine

I want to use a single Doctrine install on our server and serve multiple websites. Naturally the models should be maintained in the websites' `models`folder.

I have everything up (and not running) like so:

Doctrine @

```
/CustomFramework/Doctrine
```

Websites @

```
/var/www/vhosts/custom1.com/
/var/www/vhosts/custom2.com/
```

Generating works fine, all models are delivered in `/application_folder/models` and `/application_folder/models/generated` for the correct website.

I've added Doctrine::loadModels('path_to_models') in the bootstrap file for each website, and also registered the autoloaded.

But....

This is the autoloader code:

```
public static function autoload($className)
{
    if (strpos($className, 'sfYaml') === 0) {
        require dirname(__FILE__) . '/Parser/sfYaml/' . $className . '.php';
        return true;
    }

    if (0 !== stripos($className, 'Doctrine_') || class_exists($className, false) || interface_exists($className, false)) {
        return false;
    }

    $class = self::getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    if (file_exists($class)) {
        require $class;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Am I stupid, or is the autoloader really doing this:

```
$class = self::getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
```

or, in other words: Does it require me to have ALL my generated doctrine classes inside the Doctrine app directory? Or in other words, do I need a single Doctrine installation for each website?

**I'm getting an error that the BaseXXX class cannot be found. So the autoloading doesn't function correctly. I really hope i'm doing something wrong.. anyone?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Doctrine 1.2, the models autoloading is dealt by another autoloader, `Doctrine_Core::modelsAutoload`. This allows you to separate your library loading and models loading (if you want to use some other autoloader for loading the library classes).

Comment: Nice, but if I change this: spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload')); to this: spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload')); then the library classes aren't loaded anymore :).

Comment: Correction, you were right! However, it's very important to call loadModels() at the END OF THE BOOTSTRAP FILE! :)